# How do I view expired Secrets in the Azure Portal?

Tags: azure-keyvault

When I query my KeyVault using PowerShell, I see every Secret in the Vault, even expired secrets.  However, Expired secrets do not show up in the portal. I have every permission available, and am an Owner in the subscription. any ideas why don't the expired items show up in the Portal?

Comment: Never mind, I found the issue.  The problem is how soft delete works on certificates stored in KeyVault as Secrets, instead of as KeyVault Certificates.  When a cert is added as a secret, Key Vault creates a certificate, and a secret entry.  With soft delete enabled, when I delete the certificate, it leaves the secret entry exposed to get-azurekeyvaultsecret.

Comment: If the issue was solved, post your comment as an answer, then others can refer to it.